Java spring bean is getting created and added to the context but not @Autowired
I have a JavaFX application with Spring. I have a bean in a Configuration class which is being correctly added to the SpringContext, and can be retrieved manually, but it is not getting autowired into a class annotated @Component. I have summarised the code below.
@SpringBootApplication
public class BoothApplication extends javafx.application.Application {

    // this is temporarily static for debug purposes
    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent rootNode;

    private Scene threeCardScene, debugScene, ezzieScene;

    @Autowired
    private StateMachineConfiguration stateMachineSupplier;

    @Autowired
    private GameModel gameModel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage prinaryStage) throws IOException {
        
        <snip>
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(BoothApplication.class);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/org/overworld/tarotbooth/ezzie.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }
}

I have a bean that is correctly initialised:
@Configuration
public class StateMachineConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public StateMachine<State, Trigger> stateMachine() {

        StateMachineConfig<State, Trigger> config = new StateMachineConfig<State, Trigger>();

        /* @formatter:off */
        
        config.configure(State.IDLE)
            .permit(Trigger.APPROACH_SENSOR, State.CURIOUS)
            .permit(Trigger.PRESENCE_SENSOR, State.ENGAGED)
            .onEntry(StateMachineConfiguration::idle)
            .ignore(Trigger.PAST_READ)
            .ignore(Trigger.PRESENT_READ)
            .ignore(Trigger.FUTURE_READ)
            .ignore(Trigger.PRINTER_ERROR)
            .ignore(Trigger.TIMEOUT)
            .ignore(Trigger.ADVANCE)
            .ignore(Trigger.BAD_PLACEMENT);
    
        <snip>
                    
        /* @formatter:on */

        // config.generateDotFileInto(System.out, true);
        StateMachine<State, Trigger> stateMachine = new StateMachine<State, Trigger>(State.IDLE, config);
        stateMachine.fireInitialTransition();
        return stateMachine;
    }

    private static void idle() {
        System.out.println("idle");
    }
}

I can access the bean directly via springContext.getBean, but it is not getting autowired:
@Component
public class DebugController implements javafx.fxml.Initializable {
    
    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<State, Trigger> stateMachine;

    @Autowired
    private GameModel gameModel; // this is also null
    
    @Autowired
    private Deck deck; // this is also null

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton approachToggle;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        
        // this way works
        stateMachine = BoothApplication.springContext.getBean(StateMachine.class);
        
        //this way doesn't, statemachine is null
        approachToggle.setOnAction(e -> stateMachine.fire(Trigger.APPROACH_SENSOR));

    }
}

All the package hierarchy is under the package where the @SpringBootApplication is located, it's not being missed in the componentscan. It's like the DebugController is not getting injected. I've checked all the imports for imposters of the same name. I doubt it's anything with the generics as the other autowired fields are null too.

Set you application logs to either trace or debug and check the initialization logs.

@JorgeCampos Thank you. That's a pretty verbose output but there's nothing noteworthy in it. I can see that the DebugController is destroyed on shutdown and a reference to No @EventListener annotations but there's nothing like an error in the debug or trace output.

So maybe the problem is that you are originally trying to initialize the @Autowired private StateMachineConfiguration in the application startup file... at that point in time the spring context was not initialized yet, hence null for it. You don't need it there. Spring will load all configurations before initializing the application, same for the GameModel. Try removing those Autowired annotated attributes from the startup application and see what happens.

to complete, the static context works because at that point in time the context is loaded on it.

Okay, after a night of sleep I got it. When I introduced spring constructor injection to DebugController I got an error on the missing no-arg constructor and I realised from the stack trace that DebugController is being created by JavaFX not by Spring, thus there is a spring bean created by @Component and another class created by JavaFX with nothing wired in it. I thought I might have fixed this in the init method, but actually I just created an new FXMLLoader and set the setControllerFactory() on it, but when I was creating the scenes elsewhere in my code I was using a new FXMLLoader, so the controller factory on that new FXMLLoader was not set to the spring::getBean(), so spring wasn't injecting anything inside that new loader.
Bad:
threeCardScene = new Scene(
    new FXMLLoader(BoothApplication.class.getResource("threeCardSpread.fxml")).load(),
                640, 480);

Working:
threeCardScene = new Scene(
    FXMLLoader.load(BoothApplication.class.getResource("threeCardSpread.fxml"), null,
                null, springContext::getBean), 640, 480);

So instead of creating a new FXMLLoader each time, I use that static method of the class that takes a controller factory, and pass spring::getBean each time. (You could of course create a new FXMLLoader for each scene, set the controller factory and then call the load nonstatic method on it, but this is cleaner.)

Try creating a constructor for DebugController, the StateMachine bean will be injected during object creation and therefore before the method initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb).
    private final StateMachine<State, Trigger> stateMachine;

    @Autowired
    public DebugController(StateMachine<State, Trigger> stateMachine) {
        this.stateMachine = stateMachine;
    }


Good try, but also doesn't work, however the attempt led me toward the actual solution, thus thanks! I already knew that initialize() is called after the afterPropertiesSet() of Spring, so I sortof knew it wasn't an ordering thing.
